# php code not embedded properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter for PHP. Can anybody tell me why is this code not working properly?

```
  <form action="/TestCodeIgniter/index.php/blog/comment_insert/<?php $this->uri->segment(3);?>" method="post">
```

However, this code works fine :-

```
<?php echo form_open('blog/comment_insert/' . $this->uri->segment(3) ); ?>
```

I am very much sure that `segment(3)` exists in my pretty url. Then how come if i use plain HTMl my php code doesn't get embedded?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php $this->uri->segment(3);?>
```

Unless the `segment` method has the side effect of echoing something, this won't generate any output. It probably returns a string instead, which you should ouput with echo:

```
<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>
```